# Angular's keypress event has undefined key in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, keypress

I am using a simple input field with ng-keypress in order to record which keys are being pressed.

Works perfectly fine on Firefox, but I just realized that on Chrome, the $event's key attribute is undefined when using Chrome.

Bellow, the $event content of pressing the 'a' key on both browser's consoles.

Firefox:
[image]

Chrome:
[image]

Anybody know what the issue here is?

Answer (score 0):

its better to implement ui keypress rather to use ng-keypress, this will work on every browser.

```
    <ng-form name="form" novalidate role="form" ui-keypress="{13:'yourfunction()'}"
//your code
</ng-form>
```

Comment: I am measuring when the keys are pressed and released, so I have to use keypress and keyup...

Comment: can you tell me what are you measuring? what is your actual problem?

Comment: I am measuring the duration of each keypress.

Comment: That looks great, but where can I get this directive?

Comment: Okay, I got the directive but sadly it doesn't work... outcome the same.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a pretty solid bug in Chrome.

After trying many different ways, I realized that the only way to work around it by using keyDown or keyUp events which are working as intended.